# How do you get the Linux kernel boot command after boot?

Tags: linux

How do you get the Linux kernel command line after boot (e.g. from a shell)?

Answer (score 14):

cat /proc/cmdline

OR

dmesg|grep "Kernel command line"

Comment: Note that /proc/cmdline is much more reliable, since the dmesg buffer size is limited.

Answer (score -4):

Press ctrl+alt+f1

Comment: It will have scrolled off the screen, and you lose the scrollback buffer when you change VTs.